# Need a SQL to pull in high count per month and day for full year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which will work for any given month, providing me the highest count reached during that month and specifying the day:

```
SELECT day(season),COUNT(*) 
FROM baseball_season 
WHERE season like '2017-07%' 
GROUP BY day(season) 
Order BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way I can edit this query so I get the highest day count of EACH month? This query only works with one month at a time...

Answer (score 1):

It is rather painful in MySQL, but here is one way:

```
select year(season) as yyyy, month(season) as mm, day(season) as dd,
       count(*)
from baseball_season bs
where season >= '2017-01-01' and season < '2018-01-01'  -- or whatever, using dates
group by yyyy, mm, dd
having count(*) = (select count(*) as cnt
                   from baseball_season bs2
                   where year(bs2.season) = year(bs.season) and
                         month(bs2.season) = month(bs.season)
                   group by day(bs2.season)
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Comment: I get ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Also if I put 'as a' after the line 'group by day(bs2.season)' (for alias) it tells me it doesn't recognize bs.season

Comment: I've ran your edited copy and I get Unknown column '<databasename>.bs.season' in 'where clause'

Comment: Hmmm . .. does it work with `yyyy` and `mm` instead of `year(bs.season)` and `month(bs.season)`?